# Getting the position of the imageview in custom adapterview in android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to get the position of the image that is in listview. I have used the following code but I am getting the error as "Cannot refer to a non-final variable position inside an inner class defined in a different method". But when i declare the position as final, the position value is not changing for me. I need to change the position on item click.

```
listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position,
    long id) {

   System.out.println("Done");
       if(view == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
       }

       imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewWishlist);

       imageView.setTag(new Integer(position));
       //imageView.setTag("grey");
       imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {

             selectedProduct = mProductList.get(position);
             String tag = imageView.getTag().toString();
             System.out.println("Testing tag "+tag);
            if(favr.contains(selectedProduct)) {
             System.out.println("Exist");
             System.out.println("Testing tag 1 "+tag);
             imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_grey);
    favr.remove(selectedProduct);
   }else{
    System.out.println("New");
    System.out.println("Testing tag 2 "+tag);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart_red);
    favr.add(selectedProduct);
   } 

           }

       });

       Intent productDetailsIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),ProductDetailsActivity.class);
    productDetailsIntent.putExtra(ShoppingCartHelper.PRODUCT_INDEX, position);
    startActivity(productDetailsIntent);

  }
 });
```

Comment: create a local final variable and assign position to that like --> final int localPosition = position;

Comment: Sorry I couldnt get you

Comment: declare `int localPosition` at class level

Comment: I tried that but stil getting error @ Jibran Khan

Comment: Can you show the custom adapter and where you declared the variable ? Couldn't find the position variable in your above code

Comment: define extra final int variables for use in the inner class and initialize it with the values of position

Comment: I have edited my code with final keyword @ Jibran

Comment: int pos ;
listViewCatalog.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position,
    long id) {
pos = position;
// rest of your code
 imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          
           public void onClick(View view) {

             selectedProduct = mProductList.get(pos);
});

Comment: This too not working for me. On first click i am getting the correct position. From second click its repeating the last postion